# Font Awesome icons and Firefox

Tags: html, button

I am trying to go to another page when I click on the button, but am not able to do this. The button on click don't do anything. Can anyone help me?

```
<form id="subscribe-form" method="post" class="form">
  <div style="left:400px;width:300px;" class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <input onclick="somepage.html"  type="submit" value="See Previous Officers" name="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you need to use `window.location`

Comment: Your button *does* do something. It throws an exception that "somepage is not defined". The fact that you are ignorant of this demonstrates that you aren't using the basic tools of a developer.

Comment: Instead of `onclick`, since it's inside of a form and the input button is a `submit`, you could simply add the `action` attribute to the `form` tag.

Comment: if i add action=""somepage.html it gives me an error object not found...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form id="subscribe-form" method="post" class="form">
   <div style="left:400px;width:300px;" class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
  <input onclick="javascript:window.location.href='http://your_site_url/somepage.html; return false;"  type="submit" value="See Previous Officers" name="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```